# React AJAX net:::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE after five requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have 3 ajax functions:

onRemoveFromList - change database property display to false,
   and then call onFetchTodosFromDatabase

onAddToList - change database property display to true,
   and then call onFetchTodosFromDatabase

onFetchTodosFromDatabase - fetch data from database and change 
   state to this data

```
onRemoveFromList(id) {
    return axios.post('/todo/removeFromList/' + id)
    .then(this.onFetchTodosFromDatabase())
    .catch(function (error) {
        throw error;
    });
}
onAddToList(id) {
    return axios.put('/todo/addtoList/' + id)
    .then(this.onFetchTodosFromDatabase())
    .catch(function (error) {
        throw error;
    });
}

onFetchTodosFromDatabase() {
    return axios.get('/todo')
    .then(res => {
    let data = res.data;
    this.setState({ todos: data });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        throw error;
    });
}
```

Routers:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 Todo.find(function(err, doc) {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.json(doc);
  });
 });




// find todo by id and change display property to true
router.put('/addToList/:id',  function(req, res, next) {
 var id = req.params.id;
 Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { display: true }}, {new: false}, 
  function(err, doc) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }
   doc.save();
});
});


router.post('/removeFromList/:id', function(req, res, next) {
 var id = req.params.id;
 Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { display: false }}, {new: true}, 
    function(err, doc) {
     if(err) {
        throw err;
     }
     doc.save();
     });
 });
```

Render:

```
enter code here
 render() {
    const todos = this.props.todos.map((todo, i) => {
        let property = {
            title: todo.title,
            duration: todo.duration,
            startTimeHours: todo.startTimeHours,
            startTimeMinutes: todo.startTimeMinutes,
            finishTimeHours: todo.finishTimeHours,
            finishTimeMinutes: todo.finishTimeMinutes,
            id: todo._id,
        }
        if(todo.display) {
            return (
                <Todo removeFromList={this.props.removeFromList} key={ i} property={property}/>
            );
        }
    });
return(
  <div className="row">
            <ul>
               {todos}
            </ul>
        </div>
)
```

Problem:

I have two main components: one display tasks(all todos), and another display Todo List(todos with display == true), when I clicked on button, addToList function fired and display become true, and it should appear in TodoList Component, and it works fine, everything rendering until I click on button fifth time(different buttons)

After maybe 2 minutes I get error, like this

> PUT http://localhost/todo/addtoList/591afa29891b6f1c8fa58124 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

after debugging I realise that all ajax calls works but setState in fetchFromDatabase is not fired, after five calls of POST request ajax 
(addToList and removeFromList).

Questions:

1. What should I do to prevent this error?
2. Why it works ok before I make five requests?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are actually calling `.then(this.onFetchTodosFromDatabase())`

This will trigger the axios request immediately rather than adding it as the promise callback, so you are posting but then will not run the get or setState on its completion

Removing the parentheses `.then(this.onFetchTodosFromDatabase)` should help